# Mongo Driver PHP - Can't install [sasl.h not found!]

Tags: drivers, php, mongodb

I can't install mongo driver into my ubuntu development system. When I run the command

`sudo pecl install mongo`

I got this error:

configure: error: sasl.h not found!
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/mongo/configure --with-mongo-sasl=n' failed

I don't know who to fix or resolve my issue. Please give me some help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the error message you got:

```
configure: error: sasl.h not found!
```

should be solveable by:

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev
```

for CentOS:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102326/install-pecl-memcached-error

Comment: have an option for this for yum?

Comment: @Jage see my edit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102326/install-pecl-memcached-error

for future issues with similiar problems:

search for the error message ("configure: error: sasl.h not found!") + your OS in your prefered search engine
You might get a package name , which, after installing might solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: Alpine Linux has the packaged named: `libsasl`.